# GET operation difference in normal web service and REST web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest

I have a doubt on GET operation of normal and REST web services. I understand REST services are based on the HTTP VERBS. So, for a entity, if there are couple of GET methods, how would it differentiate.

Below is the example of basic service

```
public class CustomerService
{
  public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
  {
     //returns all customers
  }

  public List<Customer> GetCustomersWhoHaveOrdersAndOtherFilterCriteria(int orderid,string name)
  {
     //returns filtered customers
  }
}
```

If it is normal web service, it can be called via CustomerService/GetCustomers or CustomerService/GetCustomersWhoHaveOrdersAndOtherFilterCriteria/23 but how about REST web service, I assume there should be one GET operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right as you said that `Rest services are based on HTTP verbs`. But there is one more thing that is `Rest services are basically Resource based and Resources are nothing but the Url.`
So what you can do is you can create different uri template for accessing different services

```
CustomerApi/Customer --  HTTP GET -- GET All Customers
CustomerApi/Customer/FilterID -- HTTP GET -- Get filter customer
```

Answer (score 1):

1) In "normal" web service - if you mean SOAP you are never using GET - all requests are wrapped in POST

2) REST Url shall contain reference to resource - e.g. Customer not to operation so the result url could be `CustomerService/Customers` for http method GET

3) For orderid and name parameters there are more options:

```
CustomerService/Customers/orderid/123/name/MyName001
CustomerService/Customers?orderid=123&name=MyName001
```

and more